# Drupal to wordpress migration (issue with password hash)

Tags: wordpress, drupal, hash, drupal-7

I am migrating a Drupal site to wordpress. I want the users to be imported with same password. But there is a problem with the password hash.

When I user the password generated by drupal in wordpress its not working. but when I use the password generated by wordpress in drupal it works fine. Like to know what could be the possibility and how can I fix it.

> Password : testtesttest

Hash value,

Generated by drupal (not working in wordpress) :

> $S$D6GbxXam3rP12Ka/Ua.WoNtSFQ4kwP99XvAH8mPfb6CVmmZJpN4G

Generated by wordpress (works with drupal also) :

> $P$BMjlN43UhvN1KGpBxzD3oBBE9YrHlW1

Generated by password hasher online (works with both)

> 1fb0e331c05a52d5eb847d6fc018320d

Like to know the solution.

Whether is it due to any salt value added by drupal and can I add the same to wordpress to make it work.

I am using Drupal 7.29 and wordpress 4.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this after doing a lot of googling and researching.

There is a plugin for wordpress to do this

Which overrides

```
wp_hash_password()
```

with

```
wp_check_password()
```

(added by the plugin)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/drupal-password-encryption/